# Calling PHP file from javascript

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have an HTML form that calls a PHP function as:

```
<form action="test.php" method "get">
user data..
user data
</form>
```

Now I want to change the functionality as:

```
 User enters 'yes' : Goto test1.php
 User enters 'no' : Goto test2.php
```

As this I could not find a way to directly achieve this via HTML. I called javascript from HTML as:

> <\input type ="button" onclick="myfunction()" value="submit"/>

In the `myfunction()` call,
I take inputs of the form using

> var = document.getElementById('data').value

Now Once user input is parsed. I want to take take all the form data and pass it to a PHP file like:

```
if var==yes:
    action="test1.php" method="get"
if var==no:
    action="test2.php" method="get"
```

I have browsed through other answers which  suggest Ajax calls.
Can it be done without Ajax calls ?

Comment: It seems far more logical that your `test.php` handles those choices rather than two separate scripts.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send JSON file from jQuery to PHP without AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43366068/send-json-file-from-jquery-to-php-without-ajax)

Comment: Why does your input have a backslash?

Comment: @NewToJS Because the '<' of the input and '>' for back quote mix and  does not highlight the text

Comment: `method "get"` you realize that is failing, unless what you posted isn't your real code. And the fact about the `<\input` slash in there, that doesn't make much sense.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to redirect to another webpage in JavaScript/jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-to-redirect-to-another-webpage-in-javascript-jquery)

Comment: I'm not convinced any of this works, can you maybe create a jsfiddle for people to look at and maybe run on a localhost?

Comment: This all looks like pseudo code to me. The answer to `can it be done without ajax` is yes. See the above thread and use an `if` in JS to check the selected value.

Comment: @chris85 not sure how that duplicate post relates to this.... This is obviously about posting form data to another page hosted on the same host/server/domain. Your duplicate post is about redirecting.... not posting data and dealing with that data.

Comment: @NewToJS That's how he/she can change the location of a submission. If AJAX isn't wanted than the request must be sent.

Comment: @chris85 Ah right! I'm with you now. I see, sorry I read the OP's source again and it's the choice of approach/method wanted that has confused me but I understand what the OP is wanting to do now. Not sure why the choice of this method, very strange but yes redirection combined with the method above would no doubt work.

Comment: well, I'm not going to dupe hammer this, I'll just place my own vtc.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make a redirect in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/768431/how-to-make-a-redirect-in-php)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can easily be done in php.

Html:

```
<form action="test.php" method="get">
user data..
user data
</form>
```

test.php:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET["somefield"]) && $_GET["somefield"] == "yes")){
header("Location:test1.php");
exit;
} else {
header("Location:test2.php");
exit;
}
?>
```

This assumes that you have a field in your html called `somefield` that if it has the value `yes` than it should navigate to `test1.php`. The header function used above just redirects to another page.

Comment: `method "get"` you need to fix that. You did the same mistake as the OP did. And add exit's after each header while you're at it.

Comment: @Fred-ii- thanks for pointing out, it was copy of his html that i didn't even notice

Answer (score 0):

You have two ways to do that:

1. Change the value of action in Javascript
2. You can create an `<input type="hidden" name="var"/>` with the value of your var

With the second way you just need one php file (test.php) and you can do action 1 if `$_GET['var'] == 'yes'` else action 2

Answer (score 0):

Well, sorry to ask this but why not use an AJAX call? All you have to do is write the following piece of code and include the jQuery library:

```
var req = $.ajax({url:"******.php"});
```

However, if you do not want to use jQuery, you can merge the two PHP classes into one and use an if statement for each case.

```
$a = $_GET['yourVar'];

if ($a = 'yes') {
...
} else { //i suppose that the variable is a yes/no boolean
...
}
```

Note that passing a boolean to a PHP class will convert it to string.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is using on change event on your element, in this example is a drop down menu.

So, when the user select Yes, then the action attribute will be test1.php, and if they select No, then the form action attribute will be test2.php. Therefore, when the user click on submit button, it will redirect to your specified URL.

Hope this helps.

```js
$(function() {
  $('#myvalue').change(function() {
    var url = 'test1.php';
    if ($(this).val() === 'No') {
      url = 'test2.php';
    }
    $('#myform').attr('action', url);
  });
});
```

```html
<form id="myform" action="test1.php" method="get">
  <select id="myvalue">
    <option value="Yes">Yes</option>
    <option value="No">No</option>
   </select>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```